# Wordpress: stop uploading full size image

Tags: image, wordpress

When I upload any image in the wordpress post, it uploads the full size image also. Is there a way to stop it uploading the full size image? I know I can add function to unset the thumbnails, for example

```
unset( $sizes['thumbnail']);
unset( $sizes['medium']);
```

but following doesnt work

```
unset( $sizes['full']);
```

Please let me know how can I stop uploading the full size image.
Thanks.

Comment: You can't prevent WP from *uploading* the full size - it creates all the thumbnail sizes from that file. You can only delete it later, for which a plugin might exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what you are looking for.

[Wordpress Prevent Users from posting full size image uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007289/wordpress-prevent-users-from-posting-full-size-image-uploads)

The only difference is that changed from inbuilt WordPress function is that we're calling MY_image_size_input_fields instead of image_size_input_fields.

also see this :
http://www.studiograsshopper.ch/code-snippets/remove-wordpress-defaultmedia-image-sizes/