# WordPress - Disable image full size option

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Is there any way in Wordpress to **prevent content editors from selecting the "Full size" option** when inserting images to a post? I've already tried [Wordpress Prevent Users from posting full size image uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007289/wordpress-prevent-users-from-posting-full-size-image-uploads) but one this doesn't seem to be working **(last active in 2010).**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Incase you don't want hardcoded sizes, try this in your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('image_size_names_choose', function($sizes)
{
    unset($sizes['full']);
    return $sizes;
});
```

**References:**

- [`image_size_input_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/image_size_input_fields/)
- [media-template.php#L934](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/media-template.php#L934)

Comment: Fast and easy solution! Thanks for your time, @Dan

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to filter out that option:

```
function add_image_insert_override($size_names){

    //default array with hardcoded values for add_image_size
    $size_names = array(
                      'thumbnail' => __('Thumbnail'), 
                      'medium'    => __('Medium'), 
                      'large'     => __('Large'),
                      //'full'      => __('Full Size')
                    );

  return $size_names;

};

add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'add_image_insert_override' );
```

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/wycks/4949242) goes into a little more detail.

Comment: Why do we need to `global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;`?

Comment: I don't believe it's needed. I forgot to remove it when posting, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution.

```
function sgr_filter_image_sizes( $sizes) {

    unset( $sizes['thumbnail']);
    unset( $sizes['medium']);
    unset( $sizes['large']);

    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'sgr_filter_image_sizes');
```